# Is there a closed form for this mean of conditional expected order statistics?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, order-statistics

$X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_n$ are iid distributed according to $U[0,1]$.
Computing the mean of the expected order statistics is easy:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[X_{(i)}] = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^1 {n-1\choose i-1}X^i(1-X)^{n-i}dX = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Instead I would like to multiply each order statistic by the probability that it lies below some value $z$.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n F_i(z) \int_0^1 {n-1\choose i-1}X^i(1-X)^{n-i}dX = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n {n \choose j}z^j(1-z)^{n-j} \int_0^1 {n-1\choose i-1}X^i(1-X)^{n-i}dX $$
Suddenly the computation is not so easy anymore.

Is there a closed form?

Comment: I have not go into details of the integral yet. For the first one, the unweighted version, since the sum is a symmetric function, it is equivalent to the sum of unordered statistics, so all we know the mean is $1/2$ and the sample mean is unbiased. For the weighted one, in fact it is well-known that each individual order statistics follow a beta distribution with $E[X_{(i)}] = i / (n + 1)$. So I am not sure which part you are stuck at right now.

Comment: @BGM No, the **expectation** of the sample mean is $1/2$. On the first line, the LHS is certinly not equal to the RHS. For one thing, the LHS is a random variable, while the RHS is a number.

Comment: Oh I see that OP missed the expecation operator. I just read the words that "compute the mean..." and not reading that carefully.
What I mean is the well-known fact that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n X_{(i)} = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, and we all know that $E[X_i] = 1/2$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That's a good point. I'll fix it, thanks.